# How to tell font-weight property and font compatibility

Tags: css, fonts

So I was under the assumption that for all possible values of `font-weight`, all fonts support them. However, this is wrong according to the specifications found [here](http://www.htmldog.com/references/css/properties/font-weight/) where it says "The nine font weights can not be relied on. These weights are dependent on weight subsets of a font being available." and exemplified in this [doodle](https://jsfiddle.net/c48v6jer/) where there seems to be only normal and bold support (anything <=500 looks like normal) for font `monospace`. How can we tell, then, how many `font-weight` levels a given font supports?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the "nine font weights" are purely a CSS thing, not actually something that formally exists in any font specification. Also, any font can currently only model *one* weight (the OpenType specification only just got updated with variable dimensioning, and that's going to take a while to a) be refined as "this is the right way to do it" specification and b) make it into browsers), so if you want all nine supported weights you need nine fonts, and for each of those you need to tell CSS which weight it maps to because the font's internal weight value *in no way* has to match CSS's choice on what font weight numbers are.

If you rely on system fonts by name, or you rely on "not even fonts" by using category keywords like `monospace` then you're out of luck: there are almost no fonts that run the full CSS font width range.

So: if you want true control and all weights: use a webfont that you know has all nine weights, bound using some sensible `@font-face` rules. It's going to take a bit of effort to verify they do on your part, but once you do you are guaranteed it'll work in every (modernish) browser, on every operating system.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a google font, documentation clearly states the font weight available, for example:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

as for built in font, i'm not sure if there is a way. more info on how the browser handles a font-weight that is not supported can be found here:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/

hope that helps :)